# How to return value from one batch file to caller batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-line-arguments

I have a common .bat file that reads the status.xml file and finds out the value of the status field. This batch file is then called by other batch files for finding out status value. the calling batch files send the file name to the common bat file.
I am not able to send the status from the common batch file to the calling batch files.
Can someone please help?

```
main batch file
-- will call the common bat file and send the file name and a variable as arguments
setlocal
call Common.bat c:\folderdir\files\status.xml val1
-- trying to print the status returned by the common bat file
echo [%val1%]

common batch file
@ECHO off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem will loop through the file and read the value of the status tag
(for /F "delims=" %%a in (%1) do (
set "line=%%a"
set "newLine=!line:<Interface_status>=!"
set "newLine=!newLine:</Interface_status>=!"
if "!newLine!" neq "!line!" (
  @echo Status is !newLine!
rem I want to send`enter code here` the value of newLine to the calling batch file
  set %~2 = !newLine!   <--this does not work
)

))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Within a SETLOCAL/ENDLOCAL bracket (where EOF=ENDLOCAL) ANY changes made to the environment are backed out.

You need to set a variable within `Common.bat` that is visible after the final close-parenthesis (ie. your return value - and it could be an empty string.

Then, in the line after `common.bat`'s final close-parenthesis, put this line:

```
ENDLOCAL&set %~2=%returnvalue%
```

where `returnvalue` contains the er, value you wish to return (funny, that...)

BTW: A string `SET` is SPACE-SENSITIVE. Had the line worked, you would have been setting the variable `"VAR1 "` - not `"VAR1"` - the space before the `=` would have been INCLUDED in the variable name - and any spaces after the `=` likewise included in the value assigned.

The syntax

```
set "var=value"
```

is often used to exclude any stray trailing spaces on a line (as may be left by some editors)

---

(Sigh)...

```
@ECHO off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem will loop through the file and read the value of the status tag
(for /F "delims=" %%a in (%1) do (
set "line=%%a"
set "newLine=!line:<Interface_status>=!"
set "newLine=!newLine:</Interface_status>=!"
if "!newLine!" neq "!line!" (
  @echo Status is !newLine!
rem SET THE RETURN VALUE
  set RETURNVALUE=!newLine!
)

)) 

ENDLOCAL&SET %~2=%RETURNVALUE%
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! The problem is that I am not able to set the return value contained in !newLine! to any other variable. so I cannot set the newline to returnvalue and use it after the block

Comment: Thanks! I had a few  lines of code after the for loop that was not getting executed for some reason and that is why the return value was not getting set.

Comment: For me the ENDLOCAL and & had to be split like `ENDLOCAL & set returnvalue=%returnvalue%`, re: http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?pid=4940#p4940 -- I don't know whether that's a typo in the given answer here.

Comment: @AlexHall : At least in theory, the extra spaces are not required. I've never encountered a situation where I *needed* to use them. Perhaps if you were to expand a little on what your observations were, we may all lean something.

Comment: I'm not sure what made the difference for `ENDLOCAL&` not working for me and `ENDLOCAL &` working. The script in which this happened was being run from a console; with `%returnvalue%` previously assigned via e.g. a `SET returnvalue=thisString` command. When I ran the script from new consoles, `ENDLOCAL& set returnvalue=%returnvalue%` would not result in %returnvalue% having any value assignment (in other words it didn't exist) in the console; whereas `ENDLOCAL & set returnvalue=%returnvalue%` did end up with a value assignment. Also, this was on Windows 7.

Comment: @AlexHall 'tis a mystery. Perhaps you could post the code involved in a public place so that it can be examined closely.

Answer (score 3):

Peter Wright describes the main technique.

The last problem seems to be to exit the for loop without losing the value.

You can use a `GOTO :break` as `GOTO` stops all loops immediately.

It's not possible to use `!newline!` in the `ENDLOCAL` block, as this would expand after the `ENDLOCAL`, but then it's empty.

```
@ECHO off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%a in (%1) do (
  set "line=%%a"
  set "newLine=!line:<Interface_status>=!"
  set "newLine=!newLine:</Interface_status>=!"
  if "!newLine!" neq "!line!" (
    @echo Status is !newLine!
    goto :break
  )
)

( 
  endlocal
  set "%~2=%newLine%"
)
```

If your value in newLine might contain quotes, then it's better to use a technique that's a bit safer:

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ("!newline!") DO (
  endlocal
  set "%~2=%%~a" 
)
```

Comment: I am able to pass on the value from the common.bat to the main.bat. I have a question though. If an application invokes the main.bat then will it be able to retrieve the value from the main.bat?

Comment: Is your applikation also a batch file? Then it's the way Peter and I showed. Else you could try to echo the result, and the application filters the stdin stream